# Get values, not formulas from Excels stored in Azure Datalake using Databricks

Tags: python, excel, microsoft-graph-api, azure-databricks

If I copy a file from Sharepoint to Datalake, I can access all the data values. Once the Excel is stored the None value is returned.

First I get the Excel-file from the Sharepoint location:

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile
import requests

#get file from Sharepoint
get_file_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/items/{file_id}/content"

response = requests.get(get_file_url, headers=headers)
file_content = response.content
workbook = load_workbook(filename=io.BytesIO(file_content), data_only=True)
```

For the sake of simplicity I only try to print one cell with a formula.

```
sheet_name = 'Form'
sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
specific_cell = sheet['T1']
print(specific_cell.value)
```

The correct value (the one I see when I open the Excel file) is printed.

Then I copy the Excel File to the datalake

```
file_name= 'test.xlsx'
workbook.save(f"/tmp/{file_name}")
workbook.close()

datalake_path = f"/dbfs/mnt/forms"
copyfile(f"/tmp/{file_name}", f"{datalake_path }/{file_name}")
```

When I then run similar code to access the same cell on the file stored in the datalake:

```
with open(f"{datalake_path }/{file_name}", "rb") as file:
    excel_data = io.BytesIO(file.read())
    workbook2 = load_workbook(excel_data, data_only=True)

    sheet2 = workbook2[sheet_name]
    specific_cell = sheet2['T1']
    print(specific_cell.value)
```

Then the null value is printed.

I see two possible solutions: Find a way to do access the value or store the Excel in the datalake with no formulas. But of course, if you see other solutions, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue with your code using the Excel file shown below:

[image]

I got the same output as shown below:

[image]

I followed the procedure below to resolve the issue:

I copied the file from dbfs to ADLS using the code below:

```
spark.conf.set(
"fs.azure.account.key.adlss.dfs.core.windows.net","<ADLSAccessKey>")
dbutils.fs.cp("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/date.xlsx", 'abfss://<containerName>@<storageAccountName>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path to XLSX file>')
```

[image]

I read the XLSX sheet using the code below:

```
pdf=pd.read_excel('https://<storageAccountNmae>.dfs.core.windows.net/<containerName>/Excel/date.xlsx<SASToken>',engine="openpyxl",sheet_name = '<sheetName>')  
print(pdf)
```

It retrieved the XLSX file as shown below:

[image]

To get a specific cell value, I used the code below:

```
cell_value = pdf.iloc[0, 1]
print(cell_value)
```

I got the result as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Bhavani! Thank you so much for your very complete answer! I now think the problem is wihtin Databricks. If a Excel is placed in Sharepoint with my databricks notebook and no manual changes are done, I can't reach the values. In Sharepoint I see changed by Sharepoint-App. If I make one manual change, I see Changed by me, I can reach the values. If the last situation is the case and I copy to the datalake, also from there I can reach the values. I tested it locally. If I do a refresh with package win32com.client, values are reachable. Win32 doesn't work in Databricks unfortunately

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you change "specific_cell = sheet2['T1']" tot specific_cell = sheet2['B4'] in your example, do you also get the None value?